# How Can You Read Image Files from a URL and display it in Google Colab?

Tags: image, python-imaging-library, google-colaboratory, urlretrieve

Using Google Colab, I would like to be able to read in some number of image files each of which is at a different url and then display each of them. I got the following code to work but it only displays the first image (no output for the 2nd or error messages) Also, if I add a print statement to the output, then no image display at all. So what's the trick? Thanks.

```
!pip install pillow
import urllib.request
from PIL import Image
# First Image
imageURL1 = "https://www.example.com/dir/imagefile1.jpg"
imageName1="file1.jpg"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(imageURL1, imageName1)
img1 = Image.open(imageName1)
img1  # this works but only if it is the only output
# Second Image
imageURL2 = "https://www.example.com/dir/imagefile2.jpg"
imageName2="file2.jpg"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(imageURL2, imageName2)
img2 = Image.open(imageName2)
img2 # does not display
#print("x") # a print kills the image display
```

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer that works. Use IPython to display the image. It works with multiple images and the print() works as well.

```
!pip install pillow
import urllib.request
from PIL import Image
from IPython.display import display

# First Image
imageURL1 = "https://www.example.com/dir/imagefile1.jpg"
imageName1="file1.jpg"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(imageURL1, imageName1)
img1 = Image.open(imageName1)
display(img1)  # this works but only if it is the only output

print("AND THE PRINT WORKS")

# Second Image
imageURL2 = "https://www.example.com/dir/imagefile2.jpg"
imageName2="file2.jpg"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(imageURL2, imageName2)
img2 = Image.open(imageName2)
display(img2)
```

Comment: There's no real need to write the file to disk, by the way. You can do `r=requests.get('...')` followed by `im=Image.open(io.BytesIO(r.content))`